# Prevent high cpu usage and freezing on (k)ubuntu

Tags: performance, kubuntu-netbook

I have an **Asus fx553vd** (7700 HQ / Nvidia Geforce 1050 Mobile / Intel HD Graphics / 12 GB of Ram). I had many problems with **Ubuntu 16.04**, **Ubuntu 17.04** till I disabled Nvidia totally with nouveau.modeset=0 and now with **Kubuntu 17.10** everything works fine except the keyboard backlight which I cannot change.

Now my problem is every time I put my system under heavy load e.g. I run windows 10 on Virtualbox + I run Zoom video call app and run a heavy web page in chrome everything just freezes or becomes very laggy and unresponsive. Most of the times I should hold power button to shut down and it is a bad experience. Normally, even if a program or two is using most of cpu/ram, system should handle that condition and prevent one program to freeze the whole system. I was using Macbook pro with core i5 cpu and 8 GB of ram, putting under same load, system was slow but no freeze of whole system at all. In worst case Mac OS suggests that a program is not responding and you can wait or kill it. On Linux can I prevent that situation?

Should I use other distros like Debian which are more stable? I'm afraid they lack proper drivers for my notebook and/or they freeze under heavy load as well.